# Sailsjs with angularjs npm install error

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, npm, sails.js

i am using sails js backend and frontend angularjs. i have given npm install.
npm install package 
show this error:

```
npm ERR! peerinvalid The package grunt does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-clean@0.6.0 wants grunt@~0.4.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-coffee@0.13.0 wants grunt@>=0.4.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-concat@0.5.1 wants grunt@>=0.4.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-copy@0.8.0 wants grunt@>=0.4.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-cssmin@0.12.3 wants grunt@>=0.4.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-jst@0.6.0 wants grunt@~0.4.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-less@0.11.1 wants grunt@^0.4.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-requirejs@0.4.4 wants grunt@~0.4.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-sass@0.9.2 wants grunt@>=0.4.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-uglify@0.9.1 wants grunt@>=0.4.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-watch@0.6.1 wants grunt@~0.4.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-html2js@0.3.2 wants grunt@~0.4.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-ng-annotate@1.0.1 wants grunt@~0.4.5
```

packagejson file:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "ejs": "~0.8.4",
    "fs-extra": "^0.12.0",
    "grunt": "0.4.2",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-coffee": "~0.10.1",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~0.9.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jst": "~0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-less": "0.11.1",
    "grunt-contrib-requirejs": "^0.4.4",
    "grunt-contrib-sass": "^0.8.1",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.5.3",
    "grunt-html2js": "^0.2.9",
    "grunt-ng-annotate": "*",
    "grunt-sails-linker": "~0.9.5",
    "grunt-sync": "~0.0.4",
    "include-all": "~0.1.3",
    "lodash": "^2.4.1",
    "rc": "~0.5.0",
    "sails": "~0.10.5",
    "sails-disk": "~0.10.0"
  },
```

how to solve it? Can any one Help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that your grunt-ng-annotate reaquires grunt at least 0.4.5 you have 0.4.2 try to manually change version in your `package.json`. It should work.

Try this :

```
"dependencies": {
    "ejs": "~0.8.4",
    "fs-extra": "^0.12.0",
    "grunt": "0.4.5",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-coffee": "~0.10.1",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~0.9.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jst": "~0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-less": "0.11.1",
    "grunt-contrib-requirejs": "^0.4.4",
    "grunt-contrib-sass": "^0.8.1",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.5.3",
    "grunt-html2js": "^0.2.9",
    "grunt-ng-annotate": "*",
    "grunt-sails-linker": "~0.9.5",
    "grunt-sync": "~0.0.4",
    "include-all": "~0.1.3",
    "lodash": "^2.4.1",
    "rc": "~0.5.0",
    "sails": "~0.10.5",
    "sails-disk": "~0.10.0"
  },
```